# Dimensional analysis on absolute magnitude of a star

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy, dimensional-analysis

Absolute magnitude $M$ of a star is

$$M = m-5\log \Big(\frac{d}{10}\Big)$$

where $d$ is measured in $parsec$ but this raises couple of problems.

$M$ and $m$ are dimensionless quantities but $d$ is in $parsec$ and I don't remember getting dimensionful quantities in trigonometric, exponential and logarithmic functions during my studies so what $\log$ of a parsec mean?

**First thought**

$log$ kills the physical unit and everything seems fine again.

**Second thought**

In $log$ function there's an invisible $pc^{-1}$ but I don't see from where.

**Third thought**

If I express $d$ in terms of apparent and absolute magnitude, I get the following

$$d = 10^{(m-M+5)/5}$$

from this I would expect $d$ to be dimensionless yet it's dimensionful (in parsec) so another missing pc.

$\underline{\hspace{17cm}}$

**Questions**

**1.** I prefer to avoid making such a bald claim as in the first thought. Can anyone give a detailed answer what happens if there are dimensionful quantities in logarithmic/exponential and trigonometric functions?

**2.** How to resolve the problems in second and third thoughts?

Comment: So 10 stands for 10pc because absolute magnitude measured as if the star was placed 10pc from earth?

Comment: It's a reference distance, as discussed in the Wikipedia article on absolute magnitude.

Comment: @Triatticus Those are answers, not comments. Please write an answer and delete the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that the number 10 in your formula is not dimensionless and should not really be written without its units - which are parsecs.

$$M = m-5\log \Big(\frac{d}{10\ {\rm pc}}\Big)\ ,$$
$$d = 10^{(m-M+5)/5}\ {\rm pc}\ .$$

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, can you also shed some light on the first question?

Comment: @Monopole possibly if you give me an example of where you have seen such a thing. If you see something like $\log x$, then it is implicit that the equation is only true if $x$ is in some specific units. You can make it explicit by saying something like $\log (x / {\rm pc})$.

Comment: For instance $e^{z}$ where $z$ has a dimension of eV. I would expect it to be dimensionless but if one Taylor expand the exponential function it's gonna have sum of some constants times integer powers of eV and adding physical quantities with different units doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Right, but you said $z$ must be in eV. i.e. It is really $\exp ( z/{\rm 1 eV})$ where $z$ is in eV. @Monopole

Comment: So I assume there's an invisible unit that cancels the unit in the function. In this exponential example it looks fine but when its logarithmic if  I use the same approach, one can write $\ln(z/1ev)=\ln(z)-\ln(1eV)$. In this case, should I re-impose $1/eV$ in the function until they become dimensionless?